# What push notification for ios swift to use?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, xcode11

I am making an application where push notification is required. I would like to know what push notification to use? I tried using Firebase but its inconsistent. Some notification are not receiving or sending.

Comment: iOS uses [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1). Firebase's push notification for iOS is using APNs as well, see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client?gclid=Cj0KCQjwreT8BRDTARIsAJLI0KKbAFY-1NQItOQADOsTAKI2yLm0gxIloMdkMT7BqZq8VY0E6T4boXQaAhVWEALw_wcB)

Comment: Im currently using the Firebase messaging, but my problem to that is, sometimes the device cant receive notification. so im looking for other alternatives besides using firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many third party push services are available, apart from APNS, which works seamlessly on iOS and android devices. The following are the some of the popular third party services...

- **Firebase(By Google)**
- **Pusher**
- **One Signal**, etc.

The APNS(Apple Push Notification Service) is its native service which ultimately used by third party push services. With out an apns no one can send push notification to apple device.

Comment: I tried using the pusher in my other apps and its working perfectly, my problem is that it has a 1000 device limit. you can pay them to increase device limit to continue using their service.

Comment: You can use FCM(firebase cloud messaging). Its free.

Comment: I have integrated in one of my project and it works seamlessly.

Comment: do you encounter the notification sometimes not receiving in your device? what version of your firbase pods are you using?

Comment: Firebase is one of the best push service provide with free of cost. I am using latest version of the FCM.

Comment: Thanks. Im currently using FCM also but my device cant receive notification sometimes. Im only using 1 device so i dont know if my device is the problem.

Comment: To be sure you need to check in other device too.

Comment: yeah. ill try testing it on other device. thanks